# Mathematica debugging tools

Tags: debugging, wolfram-mathematica

I am using Mathematica to model a spectral graphs and I keep encountering bugs. What tools does Mathematica provide to debug? The documentation was quite unhelpful.

I set break points using print statements:

Initialize of matrix,
Calculation of eigenvalues,
Assignment of graph.
Output.

Comment: [Wolfram Workbench](https://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/debugging.html) has a lot more in the way of debugging tools than Mathematica alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can

[Trace documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html)

[Tutorial introduction to Trace](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TracingEvaluation.html)

You can give `Trace` directions on what to include and what not to in output.

Almost always click on the orange "Details and Options" in documentation to see the information you need to successfully use the function.

Learning how to interpret the form of the output from `Trace` can take some work.